# Correct use of draw method in Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, draw

I want to create a simple layer to display some informations, such as a score.

I managed to do like this but I'm not really sure it's correct :

```
#import "InformationLayer.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation InformationLayer

-(void) draw
{
    // Complete clear of the screen
    [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:true];

    // Draw my score
    [self DrawScore];
}

- (void)DrawScore
{
    // create and initialize a label
    NSString* l_sScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score : %d", [[GameScene sharedGameScene] iScore]];

    CCLabelTTF* label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:l_sScore fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];

    // get the window (screen) size from CCDirector
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    // position the label at the center of the screen
    label.position = CGPointMake(size.width - ([label texture].contentSize.width / 2), size.height*2.0/3.0);

    // add the label as a child to this Layer
    [self addChild:label];
}
@end
```

I'm dealing with my scenes and layers pretty much like that all the time and I'm really not confortable with clearing all my layer then drawing everything up again. Seems to me that It's a total overkill ! Still, it does the job...

Since I'm at the bottom of my learning curve, I would like to do right quickly... Could I do something better here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's completely wrong. Add your nodes only once. Use `draw` method only if you want to draw something using OpenGL (or cocos2d's functions like `ccDrawLine` ). You can add your content(labels, sprites, etc.), for example, in the some `init` method.

To change text of your labels use `setString:` method.

Answer (score 0):

So following Morion's advice :

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] ))
    {
        [self InitLabels];

        // Scheduling the refresh method.
        [self scheduleUpdate]; 
    }
    return self;
}

// Update replaces draw !! 
-(void)update:(ccTime)delta
{
    [self UpdateLabels];
}

- (void)InitLabels
{
    // get the window (screen) size from CCDirector
    CGSize l_ScreenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    float l_iScreenHeightPosition = l_ScreenSize.height*2.0/3.0;

    NSString* l_sScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score : %d", [[GameScene sharedGameScene] iScore]];
    NSString* l_sLevel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level : %d", [[GameScene sharedGameScene] iLevel]];

    l_lblScore = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:l_sScore
                                           fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];

    l_lblScore.position = CGPointMake(l_ScreenSize.width - ([l_lblScore texture].contentSize.width / 2), l_iScreenHeightPosition);

    // add the label as a child to this Layer
    [self addChild:l_lblScore];

    l_lblLevel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:l_sLevel
                                                fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];

    l_lblLevel.position = CGPointMake(l_ScreenSize.width - ([l_lblLevel texture].contentSize.width / 2), l_iScreenHeightPosition - ([l_lblScore texture].contentSize.height));

    // add the label as a child to this Layer
    [self addChild:l_lblLevel];
}

- (void)UpdateLabels
{
    NSString* l_sScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score : %d", [[GameScene sharedGameScene] iScore]];
    NSString* l_sLevel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level : %d", [[GameScene sharedGameScene] iLevel]];

    [l_lblScore setString:l_sScore];
    [l_lblLevel setString:l_sLevel];
}
```

Seems better to me now :)

Comment: If there is room for enhancement, feel free to comment this ! (I'm sure there is :))

Comment: Anyway, you should not do any game logic inside draw method. One way is to notify somehow your code about changing displayed values (i mean, score, time, etc.). Or if you want to update it every tick, use update: method for it. You can schedule it by calling [self scheduleUpdate]

Comment: Better ? Of course I could notify the score changes and level changes, but it's my very first application and I'm trying to get a grasp at everything step by step... Your help is precious, thank you !